# Custom Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

I'm currently trying to create my own shopping cart for a client using JQuery. I was just wondering if the best way to store information for a custom cart is using cookies?

I have a product page that adds information via JQuery to Cookies and then a check out page that grabs the information from the cookies and display it on a check out page.

Is this the way to go about it, is there a better way?

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: Check http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-shopping-cart-with-php-and-mysql--net-5144

Comment: I suspect this should probably be closed as *Too Broad* : see the "How to ask..." http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - however, your options are either server-side (database, session) or client-side (cookie, local storage); server-side makes more sense as that's where you'll be loading the product data from anyway - you'll probably only hold the product id and quantity per cart line (maybe some discount info or some such).

Comment: If you have to ask that kind of overly broad question, then you probably should not implement this yourself at all, but use an existing & proven solution …

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best to save a shopping card is server side:

Each time someone add a product send an AJAX request and store it (account if logged or use sessions).

It's a bit heavier but it's more secured, and more user friendly, if someone is shopping and don't have the time to checkout on his computer, he can grab his phone login and checkout with the same cart.

AJAX is not really hard as far as you know a bit about request. jQuery provide an AJAX function to send request you should start by this documentation.

An AJAX request is nothing more than a call to a page but instead of being synchron and then display the page to the user, it will asynchron, and just return a status and (in most case) a JSON object as response, to say how were the request if there was any errors or things like this. The backend wont be heavy so the request will be fast enough to be smooth to the user.

jQuery provide callback on error or success that allow you to easily manage to warn user or to update a cart preview without any page reloading or something.

Comment: I would prefer that also. However my experience with AJAX is not quite up to scratch. Would it accommodate the responsiveness of JQuery ? Do you know of any tutorials that may be able to help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies is also fine but [LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is way to go to store cart related information on client side

> Example

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

//Get
localStorage.getItem("lastname");

//Remove
localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```